# Delphi datasnap with Apache

Tags: delphi, apache2, datasnap

Has anyone ever managed to get a datasnap system (BDS2006) running in apache?
I have set up my apache to acceot cinnections to the httpsvr.dll as per this article
http://www.distribucon.com/blog/HTTPSRVRWithApache.aspx
.
My TWebConnection objects connects perfectly but as soon as my clientDataset becomes active I get an error saying "cannot load library/dll"

I assume it is a problem loading the com server into memory? Any Ideas?

(I am trying to get away without having to change my com server, so that i can use it on both IIS and apache installations.

Answer (score 4):

If your application is using clientdataset, it also needs midas.dll.

You should deploy midas.dll or your application uses block should contain midaslib unit.

Comment: already deployed so not that (unless there is something I am missing).

midas.dll is registered on both the client and server side.

I have 2 web services running on the same server. IIS on default port 80, and apache on 90. each hosting a httpsvr.dll

if i connect to the IIS address my system works, if i connect to the apache address, it bombs with the "cannot load library/dll".